# Proof that the combination formula actually gives you the number of combinations

Tags: combinatorics, statistics, elementary-set-theory, arithmetic

Ok, there's no problem in defining a binomial coefficient the way it this:

$$\binom {a} {b} = \frac{a!}{b!(a-b)!}$$

I can also prove to myself that if I have $n$ elements, like: $\{a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_n\}$ then the ways I can permute this, in $p$ places, this way:

$$\frac{n!}{(n-p)!}$$

I've also read that the combination formula is like this because we divide the **many ways we can permute** by **the number of permutations**. I've been able to conjecture this in my drawings, but I couldn't generalize it, so I wanted to know if there's a good way to picture it.

Comment: One way to derive is to understand its relation with binomial theorem and derive binomial theorem using another way.

Answer (score 1):

For combinations, you don't care about the order.  All the different orders that select the same $p$ items out of $n$ are considered equivalent.  How many ways are there to select a set of $p$?  Precisely the number of permutations of $p$ items, because that is the number of different orders you might select them.  The number of combinations is then $${n \choose p}=\frac {n!}{(n-p)!p!}$$

Answer (score 0):

Each permutation can be rearranged to give the same combination in $p!$ ways. As the word each is used, we divide :

$$^nC_p=\frac{^nP_p}{p!}$$

Comment: could you add a visualization of this? maybe a proof?

Answer (score 0):

Another way is :

we want to know coefficient of $x^p $ in $(1+x)^n$.

$(1+x)(1+x)(1+x)...$

Clearly, we can choose any $p$ brackets to multiply $x$ and rest to be multiplied with $p$. Hence, coefficient of $x^p$ is $n\choose p$

Also, let's go back to the world of combinatorics. Suppose for some reason, you want to select $p$ or $p-1$ girls from a group of $n$ girls.

You are smart. You cleverly put a $stone$ among the group and then select $p$ things. If the stone turns up, you can argue that stone isn't a girl and you chose $p-1$ girls. If stone doesn't come, you can say that you chose $p$ girls.

Hence, $\binom{n+1}{p}=\binom{n}{p-1}+\binom{n}{p}$

Now you can read proof of binomial theorem [here.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Inductive_proof)